# My top 10 method is not working, how can I fix it?

Tags: java

Here are the instructions for my project:
Focus: Create a class `SpotifyPlaylist` that can contain as many as 1000 songs.
`SpotifyPlaylist` should contain an array made up of `Song` objects.
`Song` Class: The `Song` class will be used to create songs.  Each song has a title, artist, album, length, genre, and number of times it was played.  Be sure to include any necessary methods.
`SpotifyPlayist` Class: Should be able to:

- Add a song
- Print out all songs
- Print out all songs that are on a given album
- Print out all songs of a given genre
- Print a list of all songs by a given artist
- Print out top 10 most popular songs.
- Play a song (Add 1 to number of times played, not actually play music)
- Remove a song given the title.

Be sure to include any necessary methods that may help. For example, it might be good to write a method that checks if a `Song` is in the playlist.

I have done almost everything, but my top 10 method does not work and I am really stuck. Anything helps. Thanks!

**class SpotifyPlaylist**

```
public class SpotifyPlaylist
{
   private int first;
   private Song[] playlist = new Song[1000];
   
   /**
   * Empty Constructor for objects of class SpotifyPlaylist
   */
   public SpotifyPlaylist()
   {
      first = 0;
   }
   
   /**
   * Adds a song to our playlist
   */
   public void addSong(Song song){
      playlist[first] = song;
      first ++;
   }
   
   /**
   * Prints out all the songs we have in our playlist
   * @return the songs we have in our playlist
   */
   public void printAllSongs(){
      for(int i = 0; i < first; i++){
         System.out.println(playlist[i].getTitle());
      }
   }
   
   /**
   * This prints out all songs on a given album
   * @return the sonngs on a spicific album
   */
   public void prSongsOnAlbum(String album){
      for(int i = 0; i < first; i++){
         if(playlist[i].getAlbum().equals(album)){
            System.out.println(playlist[i].getTitle());
         }
      }
   }
   
   /**
   * This prints out all songs from a spicific genre
   * @reurn all songs from a spicific genre
   */
   public void prSongsInGenre(String genre){
      for(int i = 0; i < first; i++){
         if(playlist [i].getGenre().equals(genre)){
            System.out.println(playlist[i].getTitle());
         }
      }
   }
   
   /**
   * This prints out all songs by a given artist
   * @return all songs by a given artist
   * @param artist name
   */
   
   public void prSongsOfArtist(String artist){
      for(int i = 0; i < first; i++){
         if(playlist[i].getArtist().equals(artist)){
            System.out.println(playlist[i].getTitle());
         }
      }
   }
   
   /**
   * Print out top 10 most popular songs.
   */
   public void topTen() {
      int[] top10 = new int[10];
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
         top10[i] = -1;
      }
      int hold;
      int place;
      int temp;
      int i = 0;
      while ( i < first ) {
         hold = i;
         place = 0;
         if ( place < 10 ) {
            if (top10[place] >= 0) {
               if ( numPlaysAtIndex(hold) >= numPlaysAtIndex(top10[place])) {
                  temp = top10[place];
                  top10[place] = hold;
                  hold = temp;
               }
            }
            place++;
         }
         top10[place] = hold;
         break;
      }
      for (int all : top10) {
         System.out.println(playlist[all]);
      }
   }
   
   /**
   * Helper method that stores
   */
   public int numPlaysAtIndex(int index) {
      return playlist[index].getNumOfTimesPlayed();
   }
   
   /**
   * This plays a song (by adding 1 after a song is "played")
   * @param the title of the song wanting to be played
   * @return +1
   */
   public void play(String title){
      for(int i = 0; i < first; i++){
         if(playlist[i].getTitle().equals(title)){
            playlist[i].setNumOfTimesPlayed(playlist[i].getNumOfTimesPlayed() + 1);
         }
      }
   }
   
   /**
   * This removes a unwanted song from the playlist given the title of the song
   * @param the title of the song wanting to be removed
   */
   public void remove(String title){
      for(int i = 0; i < first; i++){
         if(playlist[i].getTitle().equals(title)){
            playlist[i] = null;
            for(int j = i; j < playlist.length-1 ; j++){
               playlist[j] = playlist[j+1];
               playlist[i] = playlist[j];
            }
         }
      }
      first -= 1;
   }
   
}
```

**class Song**

```
public class Song
{
   // Fields
   private String title;
   private String artist;
   private String album;
   private double lengthOfSong; // in seconds
   private String genre;
   private int numOfTimesPlayed;
   
   // Constructors
   /**
   * Empty Constructor for objects of class Song
   */
   public Song() {
   }
   
   /**
   * Overloaded Constructor for objects of class Song
   */
   public Song(String title, String artist, String album, double lengthOfSong, String genre, int numOfTimesPlayed) {
      this.title = title;
      this.artist = artist;
      this.album = album;
      this.lengthOfSong = lengthOfSong;
      this.genre = genre;
      this.numOfTimesPlayed = numOfTimesPlayed;
   }
   
   // Getters
   
   public String getTitle() {
      return title;
   }
   
   public String getArtist() {
      return artist;
   }
   
   public String getAlbum() {
      return album;
   }
   
   public double getLengthOfSong() {
      return lengthOfSong;
   }
   
   public String getGenre () {
      return genre;
   }
   
   public int getNumOfTimesPlayed() {
      return numOfTimesPlayed;
   }
   
   // Setters
   
   public void setTitle (String title) {
      this.title = title;
   }
   
   public void setArtist(String artist) {
      this.artist = artist;
   }
   
   public void setAlbum(String album) {
      this.album = album;
   }
   
   public void setLengthOfSong(double lengthOfSong) {
      this.lengthOfSong = lengthOfSong;
   }
   
   public void setGenre(String genre) {
      this.genre = genre;
   }
   
   public void setNumOfTimesPlayed (int numOfTimesPlayed) {
      this.numOfTimesPlayed = numOfTimesPlayed;
   }
   
   // Methods
   
   /**
   * toString of the info of the class Song
   * @return a toString representation of the Song class
   */
   public String toString() {
      String s = "Song: ";
      s = s + "Title: " +  getTitle() + " ";
      s = s + "Artist: " + getArtist() + " ";
      s = s + "Name of album: " + getAlbum() + " ";
      s = s + "Length of song: " + getLengthOfSong() + " ";
      s = s + "Genre of song: " + getGenre() + " ";
      s = s + "Number of time played: " + getNumOfTimesPlayed() + " ";
      return s;
   }
   
   /**
   * A method that plays a song again (repeats a song)
   */
   public void playAgain() {
      numOfTimesPlayed = numOfTimesPlayed + 1;
   }
}
```

Comment: Silly question, but did your class teach you about `Sortable`?

Comment: I would sort `playlist` according to `numOfTimesPlayed` for each song. If you sort in descending order, then after the sort, simply take the first ten songs in `playlist`. Are you allowed to use classes like `java.util.Arrays` and interface `java.util.Comparator`? If not then just sort `playlist` using a sorting algorithm like [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)

Comment: It seems to work, it just gives me a: Index 10 out of bounds for length 10 for the                 System.out.println(playlist[top10[place]]); line. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using java8 or superior you can do this:

```
class Song implements Comparable{
  ...
  @Override
  public int compareTo(Song s) {
    return this.getNumOfTimesPlayed().compareTo(s.getNumOfTimesPlayed());
  }
  ...
}

class SpotifyPlaylist{
    ....
    public void topTen() {
      return playlist.stram()
               .sorted() // Will sort based on the compareTo method reimplemented on Song class
               .limit(10) // Will take the first 10
               .forEach(System.out::println); // Will print the result
    }
    ....
}
```